# Redis ios client using websocket in secure way

Tags: ios, swift, websocket, redis

I am currently communicating with my Redis instance from my iOS client using a websocket. I specify the host address and the listening port and execute some Redis Commands from my IOS client directly.

The reason I am doing that because I am doing real live geolocation tracking and executing these commands from my backend which is in php will result in latency.

I am afraid that this is not the most secure way because if someone knows my host address and ports he will be able to access my Redis Instance.

My question is how can I communicate with my Redis Instance from my iOs client using a websocket but in a more secure way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Ahmed,

I read the answer provided by @ThatCampbellKid and the comments and understand your wish to have the iOS client communicate directly with the Redis server.

However, [Redis was NOT designed for this approach](https://redis.io/topics/security). As indicated in the documentation (emphasis added):

> Redis is designed to be accessed by **trusted clients** *inside* **trusted environments**.

The internet is **not** a trusted environment and the direct access allows Redis to be accessed by non-trusted clients.

The same documentation gives the following example (emphasis added):

> In the common case of a single computer directly exposed to the internet, such as a virtualized Linux instance (Linode, EC2, ...), the **Redis port should be firewalled to prevent access from the outside**. Clients will still be able to access Redis using the loopback interface.

The correct approach would be to use a dynamic application to authenticate clients and bridge between clients and the Redis server.

You can use JWT (the nginx module suggested by @ThatCampbellKid), PHP, Ruby, node.js, Java, C or whatever you want - but you will need to use something.

I'm sorry to say this, but any other shortcut will expose your system to security risks.

---

**EDIT**:

Yes, you can still use WebSocket.

The difference is that this architecture is not secure:

```
Client <=(WebSockets)=> Redis
```

And this architecture is secure (if implemented correctly):

```
Client <=(WebSockets)=> Authentication Layer <=(TCP)=> Redis
```

Comment: so this means I can't use websockets to connect directly to redis. I have to use http and that will increase latency. If that is only option, how can someone reduce latency ?

Comment: You can use WebSockets. There's no need to add HTTP latency into the mix. You just need to connect the WebSockets through an authentication layer.

Comment: @Ahmed, You're welcome. I updated the answer to add explain what I meant. I wish you success.

Comment: just to make sure. By authentication layer you mean SSL certificate or other form of Authentication

Comment: @Ahmed, by authentication layer I mean a layer that checks for the client credentials. Client credentials could TLS/SSL based (with the client presenting a specific trusted certificate), password / token based or whatever. The important part is that only trusted clients will be allowed to connect to the Redis server.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple ways of doing it, depending on how your project is set up. You could add an NGINX loadbalancer in front of your php/redis containers that accepts JSON Web Tokens for authentication. 
https://www.nginx.com/blog/authentication-content-based-routing-jwts-nginx-plus/

Redis has the ability to do authentication as well, but isn't considered best practices it looks like, but you can find more information about it here also:
https://redis.io/commands/auth

Comment: I have an NGINX server. The issue I want to communicate directly with REDIS without involving php due to latency. If I use and NGINX load balancer, I have to send an http request to NGINX right?

Comment: It looks like you might be able to interact with redis using http request commands, let me know what you think of this: 
https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/modules/redis/

Comment: @ThatCampbellKid - adding HTTP requests will increase latency rather than minimize it, due to overhead (i.e., headers and such).

Answer (score 0):

As you said you are already running Nginx then have a look at the [Nchan websockets module](https://nchan.io)

Your Nginx install can then serve websocket connections directly and it has support for several methods of client authentication as well as direct integration with redis